# Design of the site when it graduates?

Tags: discussion, design, graduation

*Sort of a dumb question*

Who does the site design after its graduation. Do we get to choose/propose designs for different widgets?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you search through the meta of most graduated Area 51 sites you'll find a thread [like this one](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/547/1750) posted by one of our designers. They'll work up a design concept and submit it to the community for feedback.

Frequently, part of the process involves the designer hanging out on meta and reading any suggestions that have been made previously, so you are welcome to float ideas. However, keep in mind that the site won't be "designed by committee" - our designers aren't *obligated* to incorporate ideas that come up here. However their goal is to create a design that represents this community so it's likely they'll take some of it to heart.

Comment: But design by committee always works out so well!

Comment: I want to use the robots shooting lasers at a dragon from [rpg.stackexhange.com](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/). Everything else looks too boring.

Comment: is biology upgrading?

Comment: @Chris: It's not in the graduation queue just yet. (I owe you guys a more thorough analysis of your status, but I have to leave it there for now.)

Comment: @abbyhairboat no worries! I was just wondering :) Thanks for your feedback!