# Possible idea for post-graduation favicon

Tags: discussion

Based on [this question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/design-of-the-site-when-it-graduates), it looks like we might want to have some discussion about the design for the site after moving from beta. I thought I'd take a stab at some ideas for the favicon, that little logo that goes next to the questions on the right side of the page. I saw that most of the [favicons are boring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42242/recognise-stack-exchange-sites-by-their-icon). In response I made this image, note I am not a designer and the 16 by 16 pixel limit makes it hard for me to make something actually look like what it is.

[image]

I have a DNA double helix, a Beta sheet, an alpha helix, and red blood cell. The blood cell is the only one that looks decent from a distance.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea for discussion, and maybe something we should start thinking about. However, personally, I find these suggestions too connected to certain subfields of biology to be suitable for BioSE as a whole (but maybe that's just me as an ecologist talking).

Comment: Yeah, finding 1 thing that represents all of biology is difficult.

Comment: Well I think DNA has become a symbol of biology (to general public). It may not represent all of biology but it is the most popular symbol no doubt. It is possible to make a good SVG picture of DNA.

Comment: @WYSIWYG If DNA is a symbol of biology as a whole, and the most popular one, is arguable. But it is definately difficult to find something that covers all. However, I would prefer something that indicates processes at multiple scales/levels and not only something specifically low-level/reductionistic, e.g. something that captures [multiple levels](http://india.hereticwear.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Biology-T-shirt-DNA-640x800.jpg) or [hierarchy of life](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/Collapsed_tree_labels_simplified.png/350px-Collapsed_tree_labels_simplified.png).

Comment: @fileunderwater Such a thing would be suitable for background; cant fit in an icon. I also like some pictures from Haeckel's *kunstformen der natur*