# Site Graduated!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/site-design-for-biology-community).

We have also themed the [twitter](https://twitter.com/stackbiology) account and newsletter template for this site.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: This happened so much more quickly than expected! The site looks great!

Comment: Cool. And this happened realy, really fast.

Comment: Nooooo.... privileges.... why have you forsaken me?

Comment: erhm... Loving the design. Thanks for the hard work!

Comment: @RoverEye - side effect of graduation... same privileges are at higher reputation. Bonus: you get to go after them again ;)

Comment: Also see this related question and answers on the network meta, @RoverEye: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139432/reputation-privileges-when-a-beta-becomes-a-fully-fledged-site

Comment: @Oded Yeah I knew this was coming, just wanted to interject a little bit of drama :)

Comment: You've managed that - we now have an angst ridden designer, hugging himself in a dark corner. But the medics are on their way, @Rover

Comment: Wow, the graduation was really quick. Great job on the design.

Comment: Thank you for changing the badge icon <3

Comment: That was super quick..... The chat still has the beta design.

Comment: It's astonishing to see both Bio and Chem graduate in quick succession. Like the Bio theme more, though.

Comment: Also the featured (bounty) label still is in bright blue, this is inconsistent with the current theme.

Comment: On SE network profile pages, the bio.SE logo is still the beta version :) EDIT: actually, I think it's just generally across stackexchange.com and thus redundant with WYSIWYG's earlier comment

Comment: I'm really happy for you seeing you transformed! :)) Best luck, guys, you're awesome!!! :))

Comment: @Armatus The CDN we use caches icons pretty aggressively. All should update within a week.

Comment: Never been so happy to come back after a long time and see this change.  I totally thought Bio was doomed there for a bit.  Maybe there's a lesson on selective pressure here...

Comment: Wow! Congrats Guys!

Comment: Yeah - Biology has its place in the Stack now. Rightfully so. Live long and prosper.

Comment: Looks really great. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

I think the design could be still improved.

We could

1. We could make the illustration more colorful. Such as instead only one color; we could choose some other colors in combinations.

Here are some suggestions from [web-colors list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}\hline
\textbf{Reds} & \textbf{Yellows} & \textbf{greens}& \textbf{blues}& \textbf{purples}\\\hline
\bbox[red]{\textbf{RED}} & \bbox[Yellow]{\textbf{YELLOW}} & \bbox[limeGreen]{\textbf{LIME-GREEN}}& \bbox[aqua]{\textbf{AQUA}}& \bbox[Fuchsia]{\textbf{FUCHSIA}}\\\hline
\bbox[OrangeRed]{\textbf{ORANGE-RED}} & \bbox[Gold]{\textbf{GOLD}} & \bbox[yellowgreen]{\textbf{YELLOW-GREEN}}& \bbox[DarkTurquoise]{\textbf{DARK-TURQUOISE}}& \bbox[DeepPink]
{\textbf{DEEP-PINK}}\\\hline
\bbox[Tomato]{\textbf{TOMATO}} & \bbox[Goldenrod]{\textbf{GOLDENROD}} & \bbox[OliveDrab]{\textbf{OLIVE-DRAB}}& \bbox[LightSeaGreen]{\textbf{LIHGHT-SEA-GREEN}}& \bbox[MediumVioletRed]{\textbf{MEDIUM-VIOLET-RED}}\\\hline
\bbox[Coral]{\textbf{CORAL}} & \bbox[SandyBrown]{\textbf{SANDY-BROWN}} & \bbox[DarkOliveGreen]{\textbf{DARK-OLIVE-GREEN}}& \bbox[DeepSkyBlue]{\textbf{DEEP-SKY-BLUE}}& \bbox[Purple]{\textbf{PURPLE}}\\\hline
\bbox[Salmon]{\textbf{SALMON}} & \bbox[Peru]{\textbf{PERU}} & \bbox[Olive]{\textbf{OLIVE}}& \bbox[DodgerBlue]{\textbf{DODGER-BLUE}}& \bbox[DarkViolet]{\textbf{DARK-VIOLET}}\\\hline
\bbox[FireBrick]{\textbf{FIREBRICK}} & \bbox[Orange]{\textbf{ORANGE}} & \bbox[ForestGreen]{\textbf{FOREST-GREEN}}& \bbox[CornflowerBlue]{\textbf{CORNFLOWER-BLUE}}& \bbox[Indigo]{\textbf{INDIGO}}\\\hline 
\bbox[DarkRed]{\textbf{DARK-RED}} & \bbox[DarkOrange]{\textbf{DARK-ORANGE}} & \bbox[Green]{\textbf{GREEN}}& \bbox[SteelBlue]{\textbf{STEELBLUE}}& \bbox[Pink]{\textbf{PINK}}\\\hline 
\bbox[IndianRed]{\textbf{INDIAN-RED}} & \bbox[Moccasin]{\textbf{MOCCASIN}} & \bbox[DarkGreen]{\textbf{DARK-GREEN}}& \bbox[MidnightBlue]{\textbf{MIDNIGHT-BLUE}}& \bbox[RosyBrown]{\textbf{ROSY-BROWN}}\\\hline 
\end{array}$$

(The array doesn't indicate any combination, is used to only save the space.)

Here I've shown some samples.

Sample-1: Bright background; only lines colored

[image: Sample-1: Bright background, lines colored]

Sample-2: Brighter background; shapes fill-coloured

[image: Bright background, shape fill-coloured]

Sample-3: Dark background, Fill-coloured, lines black, bright sharpening.
[image]

Sample-4: Dark background, fill-coloured, lines white. 
[image: White lines]

---

2. At the side-space (at left and right side of the text area); we could add some light watermarks.

For this purpose; I would prefer something structural to 'see'; for example the image below:

[image: animals]
(Sample originally inspired from an [answer](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/site-design-for-biology-community/3024#3024) by user@WYSIWYG  in the [question site-design feedback](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/site-design-for-biology-community),  [original photo url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRCw7.png))

But not only some arthropods; structures from other animals, plants , fungi , histologic section, TEM/ SEM electron micrograph and chemical-structures too, could be included.