# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

Congratulations on [receiving a new design](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/site-graduated)! Included with your new design is the Community Promotion Ads system. For those who are unfamiliar with how this works, please read onwards!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting biology research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3035).

Comment: http://projectevomap.yolasite.com/

Answer (score 20):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Pubmed]

Answer (score 12):

[image: bioarXiv]

Comment: Great suggestion! I cannot believe I forgot about it.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Find numbers for your answers here!]

Comment: I think the modified by comments at the end need to be posted as comments rather than in the body for it to work

Comment: @RoryM thanks for the heads-up! I modified this from the official logo, and received permission via email from the webmaster for both the linking and the derivative work.

Answer (score 9):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/biology.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://biology.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884) that will adapt if we have questions with bounties. The resolution is not a problem.

Answer (score 9):

[image: The tree of life web project]

Comment: I don't know why this site can’t be reached.

Comment: @huzaifaabedeen I guess the site has gone down, this was the question for community ads from six years ago.

Answer (score 9):

[image: your one-stop source for information on evolution]

Comment: This comes from the discussion I had with Corvus on my question http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3000. It is related to the effort of reducing the "why did X evolve" style questions which is also discussed in WYSIWYG's question http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3116. It leads to a UBerkely tutorial for beginners.

Comment: I redid the whole graphic, because their logo was way too small to blow up to this size. I am no graphic designer, so I didn't even recognize their original font. If somebody wants to improve the appearance, here is the SVG I made: http://pastebin.com/BNhHqvUt

Answer (score 8):

[image: Encylopedia of life]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: Slighty modified version of their logo found [here](http://danbif.dk/omgbif/), to better fit the format.

Answer (score 6):

[image: chemistry stackexchange]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Visit Health Stack Exchange]

Comment: © [Tim](http://stackexchange.com/users/3203697/tim) 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: @fileunderwater I vaguely remember that you can also use the doubled size, for high-resolution displays.

Comment: @fileunderwater See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247063/do-the-double-size-retina-screen-community-ads-work-on-all-sites). They are supported.

Comment: I wouldn't mind advertising health.se but could we have a normal font? I find this font both particularly ugly (but that's a matter of taste) and hard to read. The first `A` looks like a Greek `Λ` and the fact that the second in the same sentence is lowercase is confusing.

Comment: @terdon I've asked the person making the ads to change the font, so there should be a new one soon.

Comment: @michaelpri edited in the new one here.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Uniprot]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Biodiversity Heritage Library]

Comment: If anybody would like to improve on my pretty crappy attempt, the SVG file is available at https://gist.github.com/gaurav/23d6abaf2e9f1439a583 -- it's just https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:431_American_Flamingo.jpg with a logo from http://biodivlib.wikispaces.com/BHL+Logo placed above it.

Answer (score 2):

[image: EvolDir - the Evolutionary directory]

Comment: To clarify, this is an important sendlist in evolution and ecology, hosted by McMaster University, which is used for notifications and postings of open positions (graduate student, postdoc), conferences, workshops etc. It should be relevant for many of the users of the site, especially those who are professional biologists or university students.

Comment: Shouldn't the logo give an idea of what it is? As-is I won't understand what the link is for.

Comment: @MarchHo I see your point, and have updated with a short tagline. I actually thought about a more decriptive logo, but felt hesitant since they dont seem to use a clear "tagline" themselves (probably since it is mostly spread by word-of-mouth and twitter followers).

Answer (score 2):

[image: If you want down-to-earth answers to your questions]

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it getting downvoted because of esthetic reasons or because you guys don't think it is relevant to your community? Being myself a paleontologist, it seemed logical to me to advertise [EarthScience.se](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com) here.

Comment: I down voted for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 1):

[image: HSM]

Comment: If the line has its own background like [the answer above](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/a/3040/6786), it would look better

Answer (score 1):

[image: ProjectEvoMap: Mapping Evolution Research]

Comment: Site has been disabled?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: original pic @ http://webvision.med.utah.edu/ ; it's a great freely accessible online book about vision. I have no affiliation with the authors in any way. It's just an awesome project.

Comment: They should have pdf :P

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: Down vote ? why ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your suggestion being correct or incorrect. Perhaps someone doesn't think this site is very useful to this community. In fact I personally think that our site is much better than a youtube channel.