# Why is the site name with the logo written with a lower-case 'b'?

Tags: discussion

Is it on purpose that the name of Biology.SE and Biology.meta are written with a lower-case 'b'?

Answer (score 2):

It's on purpose.

When the site got its design back in May 2015, Stephane (SE's senior product designer) posted a discussion about the proposed site design ([Site design for Biology community](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/site-design-for-biology-community)). Since its [first revision](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3005/1), he proposed the site logo with a lower-case "b"

> ## Logo & Identity
>
> For the logo, as [suggested by the community][3], I was looking for a unique symbol that represents DNA. It might not represent all of biology but it's the most popular symbol though I tried to get as far as possible from the original shape while keeping it recognizable.
>
> Along with the logo, all the illustrations work as a whole to mimic molecules. They grow in a seamless non-geometric pattern to convey an organic feeling.
>
> [image: Logo img]

Since then, while there were some feedbacks on the site logo, no one touched the letter casing. Thus, it's what we have until now.