# How can we get the home page jazzed up a little

Tags: discussion, support, formatting

Is it possible moderators could improve the visual format of our page a little. Was looking at some other SE's and Bio is a little wrist slashing:

[image]

Or do we have to wait until it's out of beta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do have to wait until beta ends. When a site is getting ready to graduate, a SE designer generally posts on Meta to get feedback regarding site design.

See this question for more info: [Design of the site when it graduates?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/design-of-the-site-when-it-graduates)